# Maximum lift of a helicopter in Mars' atmosphere?

Tags: mars, power, helicopter

Maximum lift of a helicopter in Mars' atmosphere?

Inginuity has been a success. It begs the question of full-scale helicopter transportation on Mars. However, low Martian atmospheric density means a low mass flow (low lift) through the rotor disc.

Low speed of sound (temperature, molecular weight, low humidity) means a low supersonic blade tip stall speed. This limits disc diameter for a given rotor speed (or visa versa).

I assume this means a theoretical maximum lift for a given power/weigh ratio regardless of size and rotor design. Increasing disc diameter, with constant tip speed, would increase lift by a square law, but mass would likely increase closer to a cube law.

What’s the most a Mars Chopper could lift for a given power:weight ratio?

Excellent related posts: [Manned helicopter on Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53931/manned-helicopter-on-mars) https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/88031/21091