# What kind of rocket design would be used for Lunar/Mars E2E travel when colonized?

Tags: mars, the-moon, sub-orbital

If/When Mars or the moon are colonized, transport will be needed between bases. Over long distances, rovers would be too slow and traditional aircraft would not work well in thin to non existent atmosphere. Obviously due to low gravity the rocket could be quite small with a non traditional design. Perhaps similar to the apollo lunar module?

Comment: Mass accelerators would be great for launching suborbital payloads. Catching them at the other end is problematic. Maybe a big Bouncy Castle?

Comment: Related post about maximum lift for helicopters on Mars: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55644/maximum-lift-of-a-helicopter-in-mars-atmosphere

Comment: related blogpost: http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2014/06/travel-on-airless-worlds.html a comment on this post suggests a dragon would have enough deltav to work

Comment: What distances are you planning to service? Do you want to transport crew or material only? Do you want to limit the question to rocket based solutions only? We all love rockets, but their EPA  fuel economy isn't great.

Comment: "Over long distances, rovers would be too slow" – There's a simple solution to that: don't build your bases long distances apart. By the way: the only one who is *really* serious about colonizing Mars is Elon Musk. Now, what does his *other* company do again …

Comment: @JörgWMittag his *other* company sells the world's most successful electric car, and is valued at 1 trillion USD. His *other*-other company you have likely used to pay online transactions with. It's hard to miss, it processes 936 billions dollars of payments last year, and made 21.4 billion revenue from that.. I fail to understand just **what** you are saying with your comment of "*Now, what does his other company do again*"??

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking: As far as I can tell, Elon Musk does seriously and genuinely believe that having only one planet is a dangerous risk and that humanity needs a backup plan(et). And he seems to be pretty laser-focused on making that happen, not necessarily for himself or even his children, but his grandchildren and future generations. He founded a space company to build a sustainable, economically viable road to Mars. He invested in an electric car company, since electric wheeled vehicles seem to be the best way to move about Mars. He amended the company's focus into AI and …

Comment: … robotic cars, and most recently, humanoid robots. He founded a company that builds solar panels, which just happen to be needed both for space travel and for electric rovers. He founded a company that builds tunnels – building habitats underground also happens to be a simple way of solving the problem with a) radiation shielding (just let the rocks do it) and b) how to haul all the construction materials for the Mars base to space (just use the rocks that are already there). Oh, and his brother founded a company building containerized smart hydroponic vertical farms.

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking: The premise of the question is that Mars colonies would not use rovers. I question that premise since the only person that seems to be seriously working on Mars colonies literally made a company that is perfectly placed to build rovers. The Cybertruck is essentially a clever way of getting ordinary people to pay for development of rover concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy, material and safety costs of rocket flight on the moon probably mean most bulk cargo will travel by some form of surface transport.

For those cases where use of a rocket is justified some work has been down on exploiting in situ [Aluminum](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19687/what-possibilities-are-there-for-refining-aluminium-on-the-moon), reacting with [Oxygen](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19940017287) or [Water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALICE_(propellant)). The water option appears more stable and easier to handle than cryogenic oxygen, but involves water which may be more useful as life support and has a performance loss due to the energy involve in liberating the hydrogen.

The suggested performance for oxygen/aluminum seems to have an ISP of around 200, giving [fuel loads of between 50% and 70%](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-feasible-is-it-to-use-aluminum-and-liquid-oxygen-as-future-propellant-source) depend on how 'orbital' your planned route is, so in terms of what the craft looks like, it is going to be at least half tankage, exact nature of that tank will depend on how the Aluminum is stored and handled noting that getting the predicted performance seems to be complicated where the aluminum is in solid or powder form- the logistics of fueling and servicing a craft with one tank of liquid oxygen and the other liquid aluminum seems excessively exciting.

One note with any aluminum based rocket is that it will tend to produce solid particulate as exhaust at very high velocities, which probably cannot be allowed to routinely impact solar panels or similar habitat structures, suggesting that any launch facility will need to be carefully positioned.